# Minimum sum of products expression from k map

Tags: computer-science, solution-verification

I am just looking for confirmation that I have done this correctly.

Here is the   truth table.

[image: truth]

and here is the answer that I got.

[image: answer]

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, but I think you can do slightly better. Consider replacing:
$$
a ~ \overline b + \overline a ~ \overline d
$$
with:
$$
\overline b ~ \overline d
$$